# Restart browser after each test in Geb

Tags: testng, geb

How can I use inheritance of `geb.testng.GebTest` for restarting browser after each test.

If unexpected alert has opened without closing during the test, all of the remaining tests area skipped because of cookies clearing is blocked.

That is the problem.

Comment: Read this, maybe it's help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096907/geb-cucumber-restart-browser-between-scenarios)