# What's the correct way to close and open the browser within a Geb test?

Tags: groovy, functional-testing, spock, geb

I have the following Spock test using Geb:

```
def "The session should expire when the browser is closed."() {
    given:
    to LoginPage

    expect:
    waitFor { at LoginPage }

    when:
    auth.login(Constants.USERNAME)

    then:
    waitFor { at DashboardPage }

    when:
    browser.close()
    // ???
    to SetupAccountPage //fails with SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is null

    then:
    waitFor { at LoginPage }
}
```

What's the proper way to close and re-open the browser within the test?
BTW - I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096907/geb-cucumber-restart-browser-between-scenarios), but I don't want to explicitly log out or clear the cookies manually, because that is what this test is validating.

Comment: Does setting up a page which looks at `about:blank`, then `to BlankPage ; to SetupAccountPage` instead of `browser.close()` work?

Comment: Thanks Tim.  No, it didn't work...the session cookies weren't removed, so the test failed because the user didn't need to re-authenticate.

Comment: Ahh yeah...sorry didn't fully engage brain :-(

Answer (score 0):

Add in your test, for save sessions cookies.

```
autoClearCookies = false
```

[link](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/configuration.html#auto_clearing_cookies)

Comment: This test is to validate that closing the browser will clear the cookies...the issue I'm seeing is that the test can't continue after the browser is closed.